# LINQ: Given A List of Objects, Create a Dictionary with child objects as keys and Parent Objects as Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two classes

```
public class Person
{
}
public class Company
{
 public List<Person> Persons
{get;set;}
}
```

Challenge: Given a list of Company (i.e., `List<Company> Companies`). Create a `dictionary` with the key `Person`, and a list of `Company` he belongs to as the values. Note that one `Person` *can* belong to multiple `Companies`.

I am only interested in LINQ solution; a brute force search and collect is not what I want.

Comment: One person can belong to multiple companies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
var dictionary = (from company in companies
                  from person in company.Persons
                  group company by person).ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                                        x => x.ToList());
```

Alternatively, use a Lookup instead:

```
var lookup = company.SelectMany(company => company.Persons,
                                (company, person) => new { company, person })
                    .ToLookup(x => x.person, x => x.company)
                    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x => x.ToList()) ;
```

Note that both of these *are* pretty much "brute force search and collect" - it's just that the code for that brute forcing is in LINQ instead of in C#. If you're using LINQ to SQL (etc) then it means the brute forcing may be done at the database of course.